# GitHub oauth redirect_uri not updating

Tags: github, meteor, oauth

I am using github-accounts package to authenticate users with GitHub.

No matter how I change the setting in GitHub's application settings interface, when I try to sign in with GitHub, an error is thrown because I am sending an old redirect_uri parameter to oauth

```
redirect_uri=http://myWebsite.com
```

But in the application settings, I have already updated the `Homepage URL` and `Authorization callback URL` to something else entirely. It should not be passing that value as redirect_uri.

I tried to restart the server with no success. I did global search on my codebase but there is no code that is setting the redirect_uri as such.

How can I stop passing the old `redirect_uri`? The problem has been persisting for days.

Comment: Query the `meteor_accounts_loginServiceConfiguration` collection on your mongodb server to make sure the `github` service `clientId` and `secret` match the one for your app.

Comment: @BrianShamblen Thanks for your suggestion. The issue was something else. I will post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`accounts-github` package will automatically pass the value of `ROOT_URL` environment variable as a `redirect_uri` parameter when authenticating via Oauth (not documented).

My env variables were being set by [mup](https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-up/) within its configuration file. The config file was gitignored, so my global code search did not reveal the culprit.

I changed the `ROOT_URL` env variable to the desired value, and resolved the problem.